# Is it possible to inject the database in Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer

Tags: c#, serilog, serilog.sinks.mssqlserver

We're adding multi-tenant capabilities to an existing application that already uses Serilog and Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer to persist the logs.

My application has a /tenant/ route that determines what database must be used to register the logging data. However, the Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer requests the connection to be provided when the connection string must be placed in the configuration section.

Is there a way where I could inject the database connection string per request?

Comment: Instead of using the static logger, you could use a factory to create your logger on the fly. The factory could be responsible for creating the logger with the correct connection string depending on the current tenant.